# How to append two dataframe objects containing same column data but different column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to append an expense df to a revenue df but can't properly do so. Can anyone offer how I may do this?

'''

```
import pandas as pd
import lxml
from lxml import html

import requests
import numpy as np

symbol = 'MFC'
url = 'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/'+ symbol +'/financials'
df=pd.read_html(url)
revenue = pd.concat(df[0:1]) # the revenue dataframe obj
revenue = revenue.dropna(axis='columns') # drop naN column
header = revenue.iloc[:0] # revenue df header row
expense = pd.concat(df[1:2]) # the expense dataframe obj
expense = expense.dropna(axis='columns') # drop naN column

statement = revenue.append(expense) #results in a dataframe with an added column (Unnamed:0)

revenue = pd.concat(df[0:1]) =
Fiscal year is January-December. All values CAD millions.
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019

expense = pd.concat(df[1:2]) =
Unnamed: 0
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
'''
```

How can I append the expense dataframe to the revenue dataframe so that I am left with a single dataframe object?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Rename columns.

```
df = df.rename(columns={'old_name': 'new_name',})
```

Then append with merge(), join(), or concat().

Comment: Don't use a tuple for columns.

Comment: Dave
expense = expense.rename(columns=('Unnamed:0': 'LineItem'))
results in syntax error

Comment: {'Unnamed:0': 'LineItem'} not ('Unnamed:0': 'LineItem')

Answer (score 0):

I managed to append the dataframes with the following code. Thanks David for putting me on the right track. I admit this is not the best way to do this because in a run time environment, I don't know the value of the text to rename and I've hard coded it here. Ideally, it would be best to reference a placeholder at df.iloc[:0,0] instead, but I'm having a tough time getting that to work.

```
df=pd.read_html(url)
revenue = pd.concat(df[0:1])
revenue = revenue.dropna(axis='columns')
revenue.rename({'Fiscal year is January-December. All values CAD millions.':'LineItem'},axis=1,inplace=True)
header = revenue.iloc[:0]
expense = pd.concat(df[1:2])
expense = expense.dropna(axis='columns')
expense.rename({'Unnamed: 0':'LineItem'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
statement = revenue.append(expense,ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the df=pd.read_html(url) construct, several lists are returned when scraping marketwatch financials. The below function returns a single dataframe of all balance sheet elements. The same code applies to quarterly and annual income and cash flow statements.

```
def getBalanceSheet(url):
    df=pd.read_html(url)
    count = sum([1 for Listitem in df if 'Unnamed: 0' in Listitem])
    statement = pd.concat(df[0:1])
    statement = statement.dropna(axis='columns')
    if 'q' in url: #quarterly 
        statement.rename({'All values CAD millions.':'LineItem'},axis=1,inplace=True)
    else:
        statement.rename({'Fiscal year is January-December. All values CAD millions.':'LineItem'},axis=1,inplace=True)
    for rowidx in range(count):
        df_name = 'df_'+str(int(rowidx))
        df_name = pd.concat(df[rowidx+1:rowidx+2])
        df_name = df_name.dropna(axis='columns')
        df_name.rename({'Unnamed: 0':'LineItem'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
        statement = statement.append(df_name,ignore_index=True)
    return statement
```